# Declaring inner structure variable in nested structure without referring outer structure

Tags: c, struct

I was creating a simple nested structure  to get aware about it's functioning process.Here is the example:

```
struct Employee
{
   char ename[20];
   int ssn;
   float salary;
   struct date
       {
       int date;
       int month;
       int year; 
       }doj;
}emp1;
```

in this case if i want to access members of inner structure i need to do something like

```
emp1.doj.date = 10;
```

but in above structure if i omit the variable declaration of structure date i.e doj and try to declare it separately **it did not require any reference to emp1** i.e

```
struct date doj;
```

The compiler did not give any error in this case. I can also access members of structure date without any reference to emp1 like

```
doj.date =15;
```

I just want to know that how is this possible?

Comment: Can you please provide the complete code where you used doj.date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no special scoping rules for inner structures in C which means that the scope of `struct date` is the same as the scope of `struct Employee`. You are free to declare objects of the inner structure type anywhere you can declare an object of the outer structure type.

For example, these declarations are the same as yours:

```
struct date
{
    int date;
    int month;
    int year; 
};

struct Employee
{
   char ename[20];
   int ssn;
   float salary;
   struct date doj;
}emp1;
```

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't have namespaces (or correctly said, special scoping rules). So you inner structure could also be defined outside of the outer structure.

```
struct Outer {
 struct Inner {} inner;
};
// same as
struct Inner {};
struct Outer {
 struct Inner inner;
};
```

When you where "accessing" the members of the inner structure, you were accessing the members of a different instance.

See [here](http://ideone.com/kwaNGD).